# Planarity at the Junction between multiple Rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, molecular-structure, cyclohexane, steric-effects

[image]

**My Approach:**

As cyclohexane should be in the chair form and cyclopentane should be in the envelope form, more the number of five-membered rings more should be its planarity, as envelope form is more planar than chair form but also due to angle strains the structure five-membered rings might not be rigid and hence might change shape then how will we be able to predict planarity.

P.S.: Answer is C

Comment: I was gonna about to argue on basis of hydrogen to carbon adjacent to junction but it turns out that for each case adj carbons are all tert

Comment: @Buraian Yes, I had thought about that too and also from hybridization but in this question almost everything is similar, the only difference is the size of the rings, so most probably angle strain and geometry is being applied but the concept is contradicting the answer.

Comment: In a and b, you can probably assume the adjacent carbon bonds are around 110 degrees away from each other. In C, it looks like the bonds to the atom (C) are around 90 degrees because those three atoms are connected in sequence (straight line). Therefore those bonds will, in reality be out of the plane to try and increase the bond angle. Because the bonds in c have smaller angles between them, they will be more out of plane to maximize the distance away from each other.